# How to create user of ultimate member by using WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, postman

I am having trouble while I am adding user through `WP REST API` of ultimate member it simply add member.

Please help me out in this issue, either I am accessing wrong way or I am having trouble there.

Here is my request sample to postman for

> http://domain/wp-json/wp/v2/users

and in the header I am sending data like that

```
{
    "username": "Fdddan",
    "first_name": "salss",
    "last_name": "Shahsssd",
    "email": "faggl@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
}
```

I think I am sending the wrong request to the ultimate member.
Basically my question is how to use ultimate member with `WP REST API`.

I am developing android app for my WordPress site where I installed ultimate member plugins and in the register user page I added some extra fields.

thanks

Comment: so basically you want to get register through WP REST API

Comment: Yes I want to get register but I want to register um user through WP REST API

Comment: all users goes to wp_users table so just use wp_create_user default function to register a user. see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/

Comment: its alright but there are some extra fields that I have been added some extra fields to the register-member form and it is stored in the user meta table but the issue is when I am registering user through site than the field data is completely different from the data inserted by rest api. the basic fields are stored same as site but the extra fields are giving issue.

Comment: Please preview the rest classes in ultimate plugin. maybe then you help me out.